# how to draw a trapezium for android shape?

Tags: android, android-drawable, shapes, android-shape

[edited part of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLIG3.png) I want to draw a trapezium shape to apply for a Linear-layout. so far I've done following. But I want to only to appear the trapezium. other parts must be not visible. thank you.
[i dont want the othe parts except trapezuim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO4L1.png)

Comment: This post helped me a lot in creating a trapezium view 
https://arkapp.medium.com/trapezium-view-for-android-584799c7e849

With the help of this I was able to create a custom view with one edge as a slope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

#### Create an layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/myshape"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.williamkinaan.expresso.Main2Activity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice that the layout has a drawable background which is: myshape.xml

#### myshape.xml

Create myshape.xml file in the drawbable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:width="100dp" android:height="100dp" android:viewportHeight="100" android:viewportWidth="100">
    <group>
        <path android:pathData="M0 0 L100 0 L100 50 L75 100 L 25 100 L 0 50 Z"
            android:strokeColor="#7e0b0b"
            android:strokeWidth="2"/>
        <path android:pathData="M100 0 L50 80 L0 0" android:strokeColor="#7e0b0b"
            android:strokeWidth="2"/>
        <path android:strokeColor="#7e0b0b" android:strokeWidth="2" android:pathData="M80 30 L20 30"/>
        <path android:strokeColor="#7e0b0b" android:strokeWidth="2" android:pathData="M50 80 L63 100" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

#### Result

[image]

#### After your edit

Change myshape.xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">
    <path
        android:pathData="M0 0 L100 0 L75 40 L25 40 Z"
        android:strokeColor="#7e0b0b"
        android:strokeWidth="2" />

</vector>
```

#### The result

[image]

Comment: thanks William Kinaan  but i want only the trapezium part. i edited the question and added the photo how i want it.

Comment: Nice. THANK YOU @wILLIAM Kinaan. This is the perfect answer. :)